# Why text get line break when scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimage, uilabel

I m doing a table with custom cell in which I have an image, a text view, a label inside. All works fine until I start scroll up and down few times and every times text inside textView and label get a line break automatically...

**BEFORE SCROLL :**

[image]

**AFTER SCROLL :**

[image]

EDIT : Resolved giving width depending on view width

Comment: set storyboard -> label -> attribute inspector -> Lines = 1

Comment: this way i don't see all my text inside...

Comment: you should set width for the label .and check . now its seems like width is very small

Comment: Yes I set a width for my label equals to screen width - "x" and it worked perfectly on all devices